# Locate models in Stanford NLP for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use Stanford NLP for .NET. I am very new to this and I am having trouble in loading the models.

I have read the same kind of issue in https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET//faq.html and in [Stanford.NLP for .NET not loading models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814503/stanford-nlp-for-net-not-loading-models). But I have no idea where they have saved the "stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31" folder.

This is where I have the C# code. **C:\Users\Kabi\source\repos\Search\Search**
And the **stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09** folder is here - **C:\Users\Kabi\source\repos\Search**.

I have extracted the **stanford-corenlp-3.8.0-models.jar** in **C:\Users\Kabi\source\repos\Search\stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09**

This is my C# code.

> Browse.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using java.util;
using java.io;
using edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline;
using Console = System.Console;

namespace Search
{
    class Browse
    {
    public void StanfordNLP()
    {
        // Path to the folder with models extracted from `stanford-corenlp-3.8.0-models.jar`
        var jarRoot = @"..\stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09";

        // Text for processing
        var text = "Kosgi Santosh sent an email to Stanford University. He didn't get a reply.";

        // Annotation pipeline configuration
        var props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
        props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0");

        // We should change current directory, so StanfordCoreNLP could find all the model files automatically
        var curDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(jarRoot);
        var pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir);

        // Annotation
        var annotation = new Annotation(text);
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);

        // Result - Pretty Print
        using (var stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
        {
            pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, new PrintWriter(stream));
            Console.WriteLine(stream.toString());
            stream.close();
        }

    }

}
```

}

**How can I properly load the models?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not able to locate your modals files try using this :-
I had copied stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09 under the root folder of my project i.e. NLP as displayed in image 1 in the picture itself the second one shows how I have extracted the stanford-corenlp-3.8.0-models.jar 
[The directory Structure of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whKlw.png)
after doing so use 
var jarRoot = @"......\stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31\stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models";

It works Simply